# How to submit a contact form in jQuery mobile using php?

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, form-submit

I am hoping that someone can help me with, what I'm guessing is an easy to answer question. My php is weak and I can"t resolve the problem. I'm trying to submit a basic contact form i.e. name, address, email, phone. and a text area. It's built in jQuery mobile and I'm not sure how that  effects the php script. Thanks.

Comment: As such it shouldn't really matter whether it's built in JQM. It does the thing through ajax, but it still calls the same scripts as a postback would. What have you tried, and what did you get out of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit your form using php, php is the server-language. In the jQuery mobile you can build your interface, but server side isn't change, also all you need is to check form data on the server, using php, or the other server-languages.